# Xamarin Forms can't share image to Instagram stories

Tags: android, image, xamarin.forms, instagram, share

Actualy, I was sharing to Instagram stories with this option, that allows to share to every Instagram option, but nowadays I found the error exactly when I am going to share to Instagram Stories. When I select that option, there is a black screen without the image that I previously charged, but it happens only with stories, feed and direct works perfectly.

```
// Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
             Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

             // Add the URI to the Intent.
             share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Uri.Parse("file://" + mediaPath));

             // Set the MIME type
             share.SetType("image/jepg");
             share.SetPackage("com.instagram.android");

             Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(share, "Share image"));
             result = true;
```

Following the documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories

I can open Instagram stories editor, but I can't see the photo, it continues black...

```
 Intent share = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
 Uri backgroundAssetUri = Uri.Parse("file://" + ruta);
 share.SetDataAndType(backgroundAssetUri, "image/jepg");
 share.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    
 Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(share, "Share image"));
```

Could someone help me ?

Comment: If you are using Xamarin.Forms, why don't you use [Xamarin.Essentials.Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android) ?

Comment: Because I only want to share images to a certain destination app (Instagram) and I need to implement the sharing correctly for Android, because iOS works perfect @JuanSturla

Comment: There are lots of people reporting this behavior, saying that is a Instagram issue. Have you tried another android version or instagram version?

Comment: Actually I'm doing all the tests with Android 10 and the last Instagram update @JuanSturla

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution:

```
Uri backgroundAssetUri = Uri.Parse("file://" + ruta);
String sourceApplication = "...";
        
Intent share = new Intent("com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY");
share.PutExtra("source_application", sourceApplication);
        
share.SetType("image/jepg");
share.PutExtra("interactive_asset_uri", backgroundAssetUri);
share.PutExtra("top_background_color", "#F5F5F5");
share.PutExtra("bottom_background_color", "#FFFFFF");
share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, backgroundAssetUri);
        
var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.GetActivity();
activity.GrantUriPermission("com.instagram.android", backgroundAssetUri, ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
if (activity.PackageManager.ResolveActivity(share, 0) != null)
{
  activity.StartActivityForResult(share, 0);
}
```

I think that there is a problem with Instagram and background's image, because this is the only way that I found to share an image to Instagram Stories, only with stickers.